# Replace characters with entities within XML attributes

Tags: regex, perl, replace, sed

I want to escape double quotes inside a XML element. For instance

FROM

```
<person name="Tiberius Claudius "Maximus"" sex="M">
```

TO

```
<person name="Tiberius Claudius &quot;Maximus&quot;" sex="M">
```

I was able to isolate the attribute value using sed:

```
$ cat sample.xml | sed -r 's/(<person name=")(.*)(" sex.*)/\2/'
  Tiberius Claudius "Maximus"
```

Is there a way to replace double quotes `"` with `&quot;` within the second group?

Comment: Since when does sed support `.*?`?

Comment: I see you have Perl as one of your tags, which is good because you need a proper XML parser like [`XML::Twig`](http://search.cpan.org/~mirod/XML-Twig-3.49/Twig.pm) which sed doesn't have. You should also use [`XML::Entities`](http://search.cpan.org/~sixtease/XML-Entities-1.0002/lib/XML/Entities.pm) to encode your text.

Comment: @Borodin Used to have. I removed the "perl" tag because nothing in the title or question was related to perl. :-/

Comment: Could you provide an example using XML::Entities?

Thanks!

Comment: I now see that you have removed your Perl tag. That is a very bad move. Parsing XML reliably using regex patterns is impossible.

Comment: There are examples in the documentation that I linked to.

Comment: I see you re-added the `perl` tag. But your question asks "... in sed?", so I don't see how perl is relevant here.

Comment: I could use perl as an option.

I've generated the xml 'by hand', using XML::Entities I will be able to escape the reserved characters?

Comment: They're trying to fix bad XML. Suggestions to use a proper parser are not helpful.

Answer (score 1):

```
perl -i~ -pe's{<person name="\K(.*?)(?=" sex)}{ $1 =~ s/"/&quot;/gr }eg' sample.xml
```

Or if you don't have 5.14,

```
perl -i~ -pe's{<person name="\K(.*?)(?=" sex)}{ ( my $s = $1 ) =~ s/"/&quot;/g; $s }eg' sample.xml
```

Answer (score 0):

Using perl you are able to do a find and replace like so:

Find:

```
(?<!=)(")(?![^"]*\s+\w+=|[^"]*\/?>)
```

Replace with:

```
&quot;
```

[Live demo](https://regex101.com/r/eQ3aB3/1)